# About associations with multiple tables (Database)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I want to associate and item to either a city, a state or a country in my database. However, I would like to have only one field in the 'items' table to make the link to either the city, the state or the country to which it is associated (instead of having the three entries 'city_id', 'state_id' and 'country_id'). See the image:

I know there's a trick on putting tables in between, but I searched and still haven't found that pattern.

Thanks a lot!

J

[image: Database modeling]

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you could use an intermediate table:

```
CREATE TABLE regions (
region_id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
country_id INT NOT NULL,
state_id   INT,
city_id    INT,
PRIMARY KEY (region_id),
UNIQUE  KEY (country_id, state_id, city_id)
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (country_id)           REFERENCES countries (id),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (country_id, state_id) REFERENCES states (country_id, id),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (  state_id,  city_id) REFERENCES cities (  state_id, id)
)
```

You'd need to keep this `regions` table updated with every possible (country, state, city) combination including where state or city are `NULL`.

Comment: While this is normalized, it does nothing but add a new `JOIN` to every query... But you're right, it does seem to be what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @eggyal: I had to concentrate on another part of the system, but I will soon get back to this. I have already upvoted your answer but I will put it as accepted if that's that I will be doing, otherwise I will update this thread to show what I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered adding a fifth table: `place`. Every `country`, `state` and `city` is a `place`. Every `item` is associated to a `place`.

This is still not normalised. You have to do the work of making sure that the sets of `place` values in the three tables are disjoint. You also have more work to do in joining `item` to the appropriate table. (Essentially you trade one set of difficulties for another.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea, tell me what you think.

Since the fields in "item" will be optional, and that the relations between countries, states & cities is already defined, maybe I could try that way:

The primary keys of the countries, states & cities will be a unique ID through all those three tables (ex.: no state ID will have the same primary key as any city or country entry).

Then I could put this unique ID in the "items" table as well as the "type" which would give the table where to look for it ('cities', 'states', 'countries').

Since there could be some changes (ex.: 'regions', 'continents', etc.), then maybe it would be better to simply "add" a new table and type instead of regenerating the associative table.

Does it make sense?

Thanks!